# Expressions inside ng-bind-html not rendering

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-bind-html

We have dynamic templates. Inside `ng-repeat` I am using `ng-bind-html` which calls a method that returns HTML, but the expressions in that HTML were not rendering. Any idea why?

```
<div ng-bind-html="vm.getSimpleLayoutHtml(item)" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    <div class="col-xs-4" ng-if="item.Account.Name">{{ item.Account.Name }}</div>
</div>
```

Here is the controller:

```
function TestController($scope, resource,$sce)
{ 
    var vm= this; 
    vm.getSimpleLayoutHtml = function (item) { 
        var result = resource.getLayout(item.attributes.type, "Simple"); 
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(result.Html); 
    }; 
};
```

Comment: To start, your controller function has an extra parenthesis after the parameter list, and an extra parenthesis after the final curly brace

Comment: Also, does `resource.getLayout()` return a promise or take a callback?  If so, you're not waiting for the promise to resolve

Comment: resource has an internal variable from which strips the layout and returns it . this is the output <div class="col-xs-4" ng-if="item.Account.Name">{{ item.Account.Name }}</div>. It is coming on the page, but expressions are not rendering

Comment: looks like it's an issue with ng-bind-html not compiling . I used ng-html-compile directive from ngmodules.org. It is working fine now.

Comment: i think this div won't get rendered, you use bind-html on the outher div. in all cases where i use the bind-html directive, it's on an empty tag like this: `<div ng-bind-html="somehtml"></div>`. The HTML get's placed inside this div, so if there is another block, i suppose the expression isn't evaluated anymore.

Comment: This is the rendered Html .  Here is the original Html <div ng-bind-html="vm.getSimpleLayoutHtml(item)"> </div>

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to ng-HtmlCompiler @https://github.com/rroxysam/ng-htmlCompiler